# Run a script on a selected file from the context menu

Tags: python, contextmenu

I want to right-click any .mp3 file in the explorer and run my script from the context menu, which will load the path and name of this file into the script and play it.
Can someone explain it with an example?
Here is my script:

```
import playsound

bbb = 'camera.mp3'
playsound.playsound(bbb)
input()
```

Comment: it depends on your operating system (if linux, distribution) you might have to reshape the code a little too

Comment: Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

we run regedit and look for:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ SystemFileAssociations \ .mp3 \ shell
click right mouse on the shell and select a new key.
we name it what we want it to appear in contextmenu. in my case, PlayAudio.
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ SystemFileAssociations \ .mp3 \ shell \ PlayAudio
on PlayAudio, click right mouse and create a new key. we call it command.
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ SystemFileAssociations \ .mp3 \ shell \ PlayAudio \ command
we edit the command:
C: \ Python39 \ python.exe C: \ Python39 \ Scripts \ playsound \ play.py% 1

Here is a simple script to play mp3 from menucontext:

```
import sys
import playsound
def play (file):
print ("Now playing:" + file)
playsound.playsound (file)
input ("press any key")

if __name __ == "__main__":
play (sys.argv [1])
```

Hope someone will benefit from it :)